# Insert records dropped fron a join condition into another holding table

Tags: sql, select, insert, conditional-statements, ansi-sql

I have a logic like this.

```
INSERT INTO TGT_TABLE
SELECT
*
FROM SRC_TABLE
INNER JOIN REF_TABLE
WHERE SRC.ID = REF.ID

WHEN NOT MATCHED
INSERT INTO HOLDING_TABLE
;
```

I have an insert select statement, and I want the records which do not satisfy the condition be logged into another table.

How do I write this in SQL?

Answer (score 1):

First , your join syntax is wrong , correct is

```
INSERT INTO TGT_TABLE
SELECT
*
FROM SRC_TABLE
INNER JOIN REF_TABLE
ON SRC.ID = REF.ID
```

Now to fetch those rows for which matching column values are not present in both tables , do a left join which will give NULL values in REF_TABLE columns for non matching rows and get those rows in WHERE clause

```
INSERT INTO HOLDING_TABLE
SELECT
*
FROM SRC_TABLE
LEFT JOIN REF_TABLE
ON SRC.ID = REF_TABLE.ID
WHERE REF_TABLE.ID is null
```